# "Native TF methods not found" when importing own libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar

Tags: android, tensorflow

For one of our model, I need to build a custom version of TensorFlow to import in our app. The default one doesn't contain certain needed files.

I followed this issue in the TensorFlow repository [#10153](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10153) where some were confronted with the same issue that I have. They seems to  have figured how to successfully create and import a custom TensorFlow from the source.

So far I successfully created the `libtensorflow_inference.so` and `libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar` files. But when I run the app and load my model I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 23980
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.tensorflow.demo/org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Native TF methods not found; check that the correct native libraries are present in the APK.
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Native TF methods not found; check that the correct native libraries are present in the APK.
     at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.prepareNativeRuntime(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:534)
     at org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface.<init>(TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java:60)
     at org.tensorflow.demo.models.Classifier.<init>(Classifier.java:80)
     at org.tensorflow.demo.models.yolo.YoloClassifier.<init>(YoloClassifier.java:30)
     at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.start(ClassifierActivity.java:269)
     at org.tensorflow.demo.ClassifierActivity.onCreate(ClassifierActivity.java:155)
```

I put the .jar in the `libs` folder and add it as a dependency in my build.gradle as such 
`compile files('libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar')`

I also added the `libtensorflow_inference.so` in the `armeavi-v7a' folder (and made sure to run it on a device with this cpu architecture)

I tried replacing my .jar and .so with the ones available in the nightly TensorFlow build [here](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/lastStableBuild/artifact/out/) and had the same error. So I guess this exception is related to the import, what steps should I follow to properly integrate a custom/external TensorFlow build as a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue when importing a custom library to my project (we removed unused ops).
Like you did, I tried importing the nightly build without success.

I solved it when trying to run the custom library on an entirely new Android projet. I followed again the instruction here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10153 and the model ran fine.

I think that the demo offered by TensorFlow uses a lot of gradle options to rename/move default folders. Thus breaking some manual imports.